# How to fix a url_prefix in flask app?

Tags: python, flask, routes, blueprint

I have a flask app with multiple blurprints. They are `auth,admin,user,sample,data`.
While registering blueprints I added url_prefix for `admin` blueprint. But I like to keep the url prefix as `admin` even if the user(admin user) is accessing any views other than `auth` also to keep `user` as url prefix for all views accessed by ordinary user ,other than for `auth`.

```
@admin.route('/dashboard')
def index():
    return render_template('dashboard.html')
```

this will give me : `localip:5000/admin/dashboard`
But I need to have `localip:5000/admin/sample` even if I am accessing view of  a different blueprint.

```
 @admin.route('/sample')
    def samples():
        return redirect(url_for('sample.index'))



@sample.route('/sample')
def index():
    return render_template('sample.html')
```

Now I am getting `localip:5000/sample` But I need `localip:5000/admin/sample` or `localip:5000/user/sample` based on user role.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried passed the user role in as a url parameter [like they show here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#variable-rules) it seems like you should be able to send what the role is of the current user along with whatever requests you send.

```
@blueprint.route('/<user_role>/dashboard')
def dashboard(user_role):


    return render_template('dashboard.html')
```

when you redirect to another page just always pass in the user role with it